# Reorganize a List with Lists in a new list in R

Tags: r

This is my list:

```
mylist=list(list(a = c(2, 3, 4, 5), b = c(3, 4, 5, 5), c = c(3, 7, 5, 
5), d = c(3, 4, 9, 5), e = c(3, 4, 5, 9), f = c(3, 4, 1, 9), 
    g = c(3, 1, 5, 9), h = c(3, 3, 5, 9), i = c(3, 17, 3, 9), 
    j = c(3, 17, 3, 9)), list(a = c(2, 5, 48, 4), b = c(7, 4, 
5, 5), c = c(3, 7, 35, 5), d = c(3, 843, 9, 5), e = c(3, 43, 
5, 9), f = c(3, 4, 31, 39), g = c(3, 1, 5, 9), h = c(3, 3, 5, 
9), i = c(3, 17, 3, 9), j = c(3, 17, 3, 9)), list(a = c(2, 3, 
4, 35), b = c(3, 34, 5, 5), c = c(3, 37, 5, 5), d = c(38, 4, 
39, 5), e = c(3, 34, 5, 9), f = c(33, 4, 1, 9), g = c(3, 1, 5, 
9), h = c(3, 3, 35, 9), i = c(3, 17, 33, 9), j = c(3, 137, 3, 
9)), list(a = c(23, 3, 4, 85), b = c(3, 4, 53, 5), c = c(3, 7, 
5, 5), d = c(3, 4, 9, 5), e = c(3, 4, 5, 9), f = c(3, 34, 1, 
9), g = c(38, 1, 5, 9), h = c(3, 3, 5, 9), i = c(3, 137, 3, 9
), j = c(3, 17, 3, 9)), list(a = c(2, 3, 48, 5), b = c(3, 4, 
5, 53), c = c(3, 73, 53, 5), d = c(3, 43, 9, 5), e = c(33, 4, 
5, 9), f = c(33, 4, 13, 9), g = c(3, 81, 5, 9), h = c(3, 3, 5, 
9), i = c(3, 137, 3, 9), j = c(3, 173, 3, 9)))
```

As you can see my list has 5 entries. Each entry has 10 others entries filled by 4 elements.

```
> mylist[[4]][[1]]
[1] 23  3  4 85
```

I want to create another list with only one entry.

All want to put all entr of tipe `mylist[[i]][[1]]` in first position of a new list: `mynewlist[[1]][[1]]` will be filled by the `mylist[[1]][[1]]`,`mylist[[2]][[1]]`,`mylist[[3]][[1]]`,`mylist[[4]][[1]]`,`mylist[[5]][[1]]` elements.

The secon position of mynewlist (`mynewlist[[2]][[1]]`) will be: `mylist[[1]][[2]]`,`mylist[[2]][[2]]`,`mylist[[3]][[2]]`,`mylist[[4]][[2]]`,`mylist[[5]][[2]]` elements.

Until

The fith position of mynewlist (`mynewlist[[5]][[1]]`) will be: `mylist[[1]][[5]],mylist[[2]][[5]],mylist[[3]][[5]],mylist[[4]][[5]],mylist[[5]][[5]]` elements.

In other words, I want to put every `mylist[[i]][[1]]$a` in the `mynewlist[[1]][[1]]` position; the `mylist[[i]][[1]]$b` in the `mynewlist[[1]][[2]]` position and so on until `mylist[[i]][[1]]$j` in the `mynewlist[[1]][[10`]]

This should be my output for the first position of `mynewlist`:

```
#[[1]]
#[1] 2 3 4 5
    2  5 48  4
    2  3  4 35
   23  3  4 85
   2  3 48  5
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

We can use `transpose`

```
library(dplyr)
out <- mylist %>% 
           purrr::transpose(.)
out[[1]]
#[[1]]
#[1] 2 3 4 5

#[[2]]
#[1]  2  5 48  4

#[[3]]
#[1]  2  3  4 35

#[[4]]
#[1] 23  3  4 85

#[[5]]
#[1]  2  3 48  5
```

Comment: It worked for you? I have this message: "`Error in transpose(.) : Item 1 of list input is not an atomic vector`"

Comment: Could you put the output, please?

Comment: This is not my idea. The list should have length=5` . Its ok, but the first entry should gather all the first entries of `mylist` list.

Comment: @DiogoBastos I only extracted the first list element to show the output